# set<> class, when I insert into the class, it doesn't accept my < operator

Tags: c++, class, set

```
class Tuple
{
private:
    vector<string> values;
public:
    Tuple(vector<Parameter> newValues)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < newValues.size(); i++)
        {
            string val = newValues[i].getValue();
            values.push_back(val);
        }
    }

    Tuple(vector<string> newAttributes)
    {
        values = newAttributes;
    }

    ~Tuple()
    {

    }

    bool operator < (Tuple &tup)
    {
        if(values < tup.getStringVec())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    bool operator <= (Tuple &tup)
    {
        if(values <= tup.getStringVec())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    bool operator > (Tuple &tup)
    {
        if(values > tup.getStringVec())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    bool operator >= (Tuple &tup)
    {
        if(values >= tup.getStringVec())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};


class Relation
{
private:

    set<Tuple> tupleSet;
public:
    Relation():
    {

    }

    ~Relation()
    {

    }

    void addToTupleSet(Tuple newTuple)
    {
        tupleSet.insert(newTuple); //<<this causes the problem
    }

};
```

Comment: And by "doesn't accept", what do you mean? What sort of error message are you getting?

Comment: Your operator needs to be `const`, as in `bool operator <(const Tuple&) const`, and fyi, the only one you need to implement for `std::set` is `operator <`, as it uses a strict weak order, and `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` implies `a == b`.

Comment: But if you're going to implement one, you should implement them all.  If `operator<` makes sense for your class, so do all the other comparison operators.  And if `operator<` *doesn't* make sense for your class, then you shouldn't implement it just to satisfy `std::set`, you should use a seperate, named comparator, who's name describes its function.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  In many cases, you can implement the other comparison operators in terms of `operator <`.  For maintenance purposes, that's probably a good idea.

Comment: @user2975481: Your code does not declare `Tuple::getStringVec` function. So, this is the compile error your code will immediately trigger. It has nothing to do with any `set<>`. If you get a different error, this this must be fake code. Post real code.

Comment: Joe Z is right, you should provide error output when asking questions like this.

Comment: @JoeZ: Yes, I agree.  Although I don't tend to implement `operator==` in terms of `operator<`, because it's unnecessarily wasteful, imo.

Comment: @JoeZ agreed. compliant with strict weak ordering, you can implement *all* of them with just `operator <`. Ex: `a != b` is `(a < b) || (b < a)`, or `a <= b` is `!(b < a)`, or `a >= b` is `!(a < b)`, etc. Defining the rest is, of course, at the behest of the coder. If they want to define all the operators, used or not, thats certainly their call. But that nicety (if you want to call it that) is the reason it is used in standard library ordered containers to begin with.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :  Yeah, I was mainly referring to the other relative operators (greater than, greater-or-equal, less-or-equal).  Implementing `operator==` and `operator!=` that way is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default comparator for `std::set` uses `std::less<T>`, which requires the object be exposed to an `operator <` of some form. This will be generally one of two forms:

A free function, like this:

```
bool operator <(const Tuple& arg1, const Tuple& arg2);
```

or a member function, like this:

```
class Tuple
{
public:
    bool operator <(const Tuple& arg) const
    {
        // comparison code goes here
    }
};
```

If you don't want to implement `operator <` just for use in a `std::set` you can certainly implement your own binary comparator type directly and use that as the comparator alternative to `std::less<T>`. Whether you do is your call, and a different solution to a different question (i.e. how to do that, which Niyaz covered in another answer).

Your code, slightly modified to not suck in namespace `std` and using references where appropriate (you may want to take a look at those, btw, as they will significantly reduce your time spent copying data to and fro).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// I added this, as your source included no such definition 
class Parameter
{
public:
    Parameter(const std::string s) : s(s) {}

    const std::string& getValue() const { return s; }

private:
    std::string s;
};

class Tuple
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> values;

public:
    Tuple(const std::vector<Parameter>& newValues)
    {
        for(auto val : newValues)
            values.push_back(val.getValue());
    }

    Tuple(const std::vector<std::string>& newAttributes)
        : values(newAttributes)
    {
    }

    // note const member and parameter. neither the passed object nor
    //  this object should be modified during a comparison operation.
    bool operator < (const Tuple &tup) const
    {
        return values < tup.values;
    }
};


class Relation
{
private:
    std::set<Tuple> tupleSet;

public:
    void addToTupleSet(const Tuple& tup)
    {
        tupleSet.insert(tup);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Tuple tup({"a","b","c"});
    Relation rel;

    rel.addToTupleSet(tup);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate must provide operator like:

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator() ( const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs )
    {
        // here's the comparison logic
        return bool_value;
    }
};
```

and specify it as the set's comparator:

```
std::set<Tuple, Compare> tupleSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below for operator "<"

```
bool operator < (const Tuple &tup) const
{
    /*if(values < tup.getStringVec())
        return true;*/             //getStringVec undefined, so comment out temporarily

    return false;
}
```